# Edit localization files from web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-i18n

I'm developing backend for mobile apps on Rails.

Features:

- server send json with specific locale when user select region and language from mobile app
- server have web interface for admins
- admins can change locale from web interface for specific region

Where is better to store locales for mobile apps? I think raw json files on the server is a bad choice. I'm inclined to store it in DB and then convert to json and send to mobile app.

And how to edit them? Any tools for external i18n locales

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copycopter? http://copycopter.com/

It used to be a paid for service, but now it's open source. It gives translators a nice web interface to edit localisation (I think everything happens in the browser clientside).

It has a bit of setup (details here: https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server ) but could be worth it if you have a tonne of internationalisation.

Comment: No, it's not what I need. First of all it is out of date. And I don't want to setup additional server